# Vaadin 23 restore tabs state after external authentication with IdP

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

I implemented layouts - `MainLayout` and `JobsLayout` with `@ParentLayout(MainLayout.class)`

The application looks like:

[image]

Currently I'm fully authenticated and accessed the path `Jobs -> Post a Job`
`Post a Job` route requires from user to be fully authenticated. For authentication, I use Keycloak.

The issue is with not-authenticated user which would like to access `Post a Job` route.
At this point, the system correctly forwards the user to Keycloak login page and then returns to `/jobs/create` route. Everything works fine except the tabs state is not restored:

As you may see from the picture below:

[image]

The `Home` and `All Jobs` tabs are selected.

Is there any way to select `Jobs` and `Post a Job` tabs instead? Such tabs are located in layouts and I don't know how to access such components from `Post a Job` view

Comment: You would need to add the location to the URL and implement BeforeEnterObserver. There you can then activate the correct tab.

Comment: Thank you! Works! One additional, not related question - how to properly get the current url? Is it possible to get it somehow from `com.vaadin.flow.component.UI` object?

Comment: When you implement BeforeEnterObserver you can get the Location from the Event that is passed to that method

Comment: Yes, everything works fine there. But right now I'm trying to implement the generic login method which redirects me to Keyclock. There I'd like to preserve the user current location and I unable to get the current url inside the button click event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137890/vaadin23-how-to-get-the-current-application-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Question how to activate the tab**

You would need to add the location to the URL and implement BeforeEnterObserver. There you can then activate the correct tab.

**2. Question how to get the current URL**

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage()
               .executeJs("return window.location.href")
               .then(jsonValue -> System.out.println(jsonValue.asString()));
```