# Vaadin23 how to get the current application url

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

Looks like previously it was possible to get the current location url (url in the browser location bar) by `Page.getCurrent().getLocation();`

How to get the current application url in Vaadin23? Is it possible with `com.vaadin.flow.component.UI` object?

I tried

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().fetchCurrentURL(currentUrl -> {
   System.out.println("!!!: " + currentUrl);
});
```

but this callback is never invoked.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use JavaScript:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage()
            .executeJs("return window.location.href")
            .then(jsonValue -> System.out.println(jsonValue.asString()));
```

But

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().fetchCurrentURL(System.out::println);
```

does the same internally.

Comment: Thank you! I invoked this logic from incorrect context(from Spring bean from my service layer). It doesn't work there. But directly from Vaadin button click handler it works perfectly! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: In that case UI.getCurrent().getPage().fetchCurrentURL(System.out::println); would work too ;-)